# Rewriting CHOOSE Function (with array) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets (let's name them A and B)

in worksheet A, column N shows the scores, while column D shows the students' names, I want to find the highest score and show the student's name

since VLOOKUP only looks to the right (but column D is on column N's left), I searched and found this method of incorporating CHOOSE function to achieve "looking to anywhere in the table"

so in normal excel function, it would be written like this

```
B3=VLOOKUP(MAX('A'!N2:N296),CHOOSE({1,2},'A'!N2:N296,'A'!D2:D296),2,0)
```

attempting to translate the function into VBA code, I tried this:

```
Range("B3").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("A").Range("N2:N296")), WorksheetFunction.Choose([1, 2], Worksheets("A").Range("N2:N296"), Worksheets("A").Range("D2:D296")), 2, 0)
```

I get the error message "Unable to get the CHOOSE property of the worksheetfunction class"

Comment: Is it a MUST to have it in VBA or may a worksheet formula okay also?

Comment: Use index match not vlookup and you avoid the choose with an array.

Comment: hi Asger, ya unfortunately that's the requirement... I figure may be I expressed the array incorrectly, but I can't find how's right

Comment: @ScottCraner sir do you know how to express the array in this context (Choose)?

Comment: Do not use that formula: `Range("B3")=Worksheets("A").Range("D" & Application.Match(Application.Max(Worksheets("A").Range("N:N")),Worksheets("A").Range("N:N"),0))`

Comment: The worksheet formula would be `=INDEX('A'!D:D,MATCH(MAX('A'!N:N),'A'!N:N,0))`  This is a standard formula and does not need an array.

Comment: thanks I'll try again

Comment: but meanwhile I'm still curious about how to express that array aha...

Comment: why not wrap the formula in Evaluate adding the parent sheets?

Comment: Just use the [VBA Choose function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/choose-function).

Answer (score 0):

All worksheet formulas can be used with vba. For some there are direct alternatives in vba. For better readability it makes sense to break the code down into single lines and use variables:

```
Option Explicit
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54380167/rewriting-choose-function-with-array-in-vba
'Rewriting CHOOSE Function (with array) in VBA

Sub FindStudentWithMaxScore()
Dim MaxScore As Integer, IndexOfStudent As Integer
Dim StudentName As String
Dim ShA As Worksheet, ShB As Worksheet

Set ShA = Sheets("A")
Set ShB = Sheets("B")

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        MaxScore = .Max(ShA.Range("N:N"))
        IndexOfStudent = .Match(MaxScore, ShA.Range("N:N"))
        StudentName = .Index(ShA.Range("D:D"), IndexOfStudent)
        'Debug.Print StudentName
        ShB.Range("B3").Value = StudentName
    End With

End Sub
```